# Typescript: generics type for nested functions

Tags: angular, typescript, generics, nested, angular6

I have looked for answers to this problem but I can not implement them correctly. Maybe you can tell me the right way.

I'll explain: I want to use typescript generics not to use any more 'Any' in my methods.

I am writing the code and what I would like to do.

**IN THE COMPONENT:**

```
this.DatabaseService.getCollection <IUser> ('users', 'lastname'). subscribe (loadData =>
{
    this.listUser = loadData;
});
```

when I call getCollection () I will call the following nested methods:

- getCollectionSnapshot()
- getCollectionRef()

I want the type (IUser) passed to getCollection  () to be forwarded to the nitidicated methods until you reach getCollectionRef () obtaining a return collection of this type: collection

**FILE SERVICE: database.service.ts**

```
getCollection <T> (path: string, sortBy ?: string): Observable <T []>
{
    // >>>how do I pass the type (T) to getCollectionSnapshot() ? 

    return this.getCollectionSnapshot (path, sortBy) .pipe (
    map (changes =>
    {
        return changes.map (change =>
        {
            const data = change.payload.doc.data ();
            const id = change.payload.doc.id;
            return {id, ... data};
        });
     }
     ));
}


getCollectionSnapshot (path: string, sortBy ?: string): Observable <any []>
{
    return this.getCollectionRef (path, sortBy) .snapshotChanges ();
}



getCollectionRef (path: string, sortBy ?: string): AngularFirestoreCollection
{
    if (sortBy === undefined)
    {
      return this.afs.collection (path);
    }
    else
    {
      return this.afs.collection (path, ref => ref.orderBy (sortBy));
    }
}
```

Thank you ! I hope to fill my gap in generics

Comment: not sure if I get it right, but if you want to pass the "generics" to the afs.collection() method, this won't work as the generics is not available at runtime. it's more of a hint for compiler and intellisense, the best you could do is to `getCollectionRef<T> (path: string, sortBy ?: string): AngularFirestoreCollection<T>`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if i understand your problem. You want to pass the type parameter given for the method *getCollection* to the methods called within *getCollection*. If that's the case would this fit for you:

```js
getCollection <T> (path: string, sortBy ?: string): Observable <T []>
{ 

    return this.getCollectionSnapshot<T> (path, sortBy) .pipe (
    map (changes =>
    {
        return changes.map (change =>
        {
            const data = change.payload.doc.data ();
            const id = change.payload.doc.id;
            return {id, ... data};
        });
     }
     ));
}


getCollectionSnapshot<T> (path: string, sortBy ?: string): Observable <any []>
{
    return this.getCollectionRef<T> (path, sortBy) .snapshotChanges ();
}

getCollectionRef<T> (path: string, sortBy ?: string): AngularFirestoreCollection
{
    if (sortBy === undefined)
    {
         return this.afs.collection (path);
    }
    else
    {
         return this.afs.collection (path, ref => ref.orderBy (sortBy));
    }
}
```

notice the changes:

getCollectionSnapshot **<T>**(...

getCollectionRef **<T>**(...

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. the compiler still tells me some errors. If I can not solve I'll write to you.

Thanks again for today!